# Get the highest value of array query mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, count

With a big Thanks to others here i get this query now. its working fine, but i would need to get just the highest value of the post_id (how_many). it seems not possible to set a MAX(count(*)) on that. so how could i change this to get only the highest count by every id? i just need the value of every id where count == highest. how could i do this? thanks for any help.

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results('select 
    posts_id, value,count(*) as how_many
From wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value
group by
    posts_id, value
order by count(*) desc');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
```

i would need something like order by MAX((count(*)) or MAX((count(how_many))

i already read this but i dont know how to use this for my purpose [Filtering log file using COUNT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599823/filtering-log-file-using-count-group-by-order-by-max)

this is an example of the output i get now. so number [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599823/filtering-log-file-using-count-group-by-order-by-max) should not appear because number [0] has been voted 2 times. (how_many). i just need every id 1x in the output. no id shouldt appear twice or more. cause just the highest count is needed. thanks and sorry for the bad english.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 336
            [value] => 8
            [how_many] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 336
            [value] => 7
            [how_many] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 380
            [value] => 5
            [how_many] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 378
            [value] => 7
            [how_many] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 329
            [value] => 2
            [how_many] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 327
            [value] => 3
            [how_many] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: `i just need the value of every id`  That is exactly what you have now. Be more specific.

Comment: I think you're mixing up some things here. COUNT just, well, counts how many posts are. While MAX will select the highest value from the column. If you want to select the largest post(by the number assigned to it) you would use SELECT MAX(post_id)...

Comment: sorry my description wasn't that good i edit the question above. @Andrei yes i need the highest value from the count - but just 1x per id.  thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the resulting groups in a `HAVING` clause based on a match against a subquery for the maximal count:

```sql
SELECT   posts_id, value, COUNT(*) AS how_many
FROM     wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value t1
GROUP BY posts_id, value
HAVING   how_many = (
           SELECT   COUNT(*)
           FROM     wp_mrp_rating_item_entry_value t2
           WHERE    t2.posts_id = t1.posts_id
           GROUP BY t2.value
           ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           LIMIT    1
         )
```

Comment: you are the best. thank you very much great job its working absolutely fine. im very happy now.   regards